# C# class documentation in a printable form

Tags: c#, documentation, sandcastle

Our C# source code is comprehensively documented using the usual Sandcastle/XML notation. We use [SHFB](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) to compile this into a MSDN-style documentation website.

We now need to<sup>*1</sup> **compile the documentation into a printable form**. Ideally, we would like a PDF document but the specific format is less important than its printability. It is important, but not critical, that the documentation looks relatively professional and can be branded with the corporate logos, etc.

**Is there a mostly pain-free way to do this?**  I don't think individually printing every page of the documentation website is a practical choice. The intermediate XML documentation files can, in principle, be transformed into a useable format but maybe there is already a viable and maintained solution for this task?

<sup>*1 - for reasons that I don't fully comprehend.</sup>

Comment: This is a big *what if*, but what if you provided XSLT's to convert to OOXML or OpenOffice's format? That'd be one potential solution. Perhaps somebody has started down this road.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Yes - that is along the lines of what I was thinking.  It seems a lot of work for a one-off task though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a mostly pain-free way to do this?

No, DO not do it. It makes zero sense for a class level documentation - noone will ever read it. TAll hyperlinks do not work, would have to be changed to page references.

> Our C# source code is comprehensively documented using the usual Sandcastle/XML notation.

No, it is not. It is documented the normal XML documentation notation. Sandcastle did not invent it.

NOw, if you really have to do it:

http://www.innovasys.com/products/dx2011/csdocumentation.aspx?cpid=gawdxcs&gclid=COiJq5To8qwCFQGHDgod900o0g

is pretty much the best you can get to. The are specialized in exactly that (multi target stuff). They also handle the additional pages etc. which is needed - the pure clas reference, without index, jsut printed, with hyperlinks instead of page references is basically tree destruction without any sense.

Comment: "It makes zero sense for a class level documentation".  Yes, I don't disagree in the slightest. We still need to do it.

Comment: "documented using the usual Sandcastle/XML notation" What I mean is: we use the usual XML-style documentation comments, using the tags supported by Sandcastle.

Comment: Yes, but you seem not t obe aware that with the exceptio nfof 1 tag (inheritdoc) that is not a sandcastle spec but a C# level specification.

Comment: As I understand, the C# spec says the compiler will process any tag that is valid XML (with the format of some being explicitly validated). I'm indicating that we stick to the subset supported by Sandcastle rather than, say, NDoc.

Answer (score 0):

[Ndoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) has a [Latex documentor](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/content/latex.htm) plug-in.  NDoc supports all documentation tags supported by Sandcastle, so that should be able to compile the documentation into a Latex file.  This can then be used to create, for example, a Postscript document for printing.

Comment: I haven't actually tried this yet - but it looks like the most promising direction so far.

Comment: While I'm sure this would work for .Net 1.1 code, the original NDoc is no longers supported and I failed using it with .Net 4.0 code. I'll try again with the NDoc3 project sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [Help and Manual can import Sandcastle projects](http://www.componentsource.com/news/2010/06/08/help-manual-professional.html) directly and then output them in various formats (including printable ones).

I haven't tried this myself, though. I'd be interested to hear experiences from anyone who has.